# Is there such a thing as a topological fluid with reasonable rules?

Tags: graph-theory, fluid-dynamics

I would like to know if this mathematical concept already exists (and if so, what is the name of it?):

The idea is of a "topological fluid". What this means is a set of points and a list of which points are "neighbours" to other points. (In analogy with a fluid where molecules know about their neighbours through molecular forces.) [The neighbour list may or may not also have a distance between 0 and 1 to its neighbour].

These points are not embedded in any space, the geometry comes entirely from the list of connections. We define a distance between 2 points as the shortest number of steps from neighbour to neighbour.

What makes this a fluid is that the points can change their list of neighbours to points a minimum "distance" away (given certain predefined rules). So that points can move about in this "fluid".

Basically this is changing the topology of a graph step by step but keeping the number of nodes the same.

I have been trying to come up with some rules which would allow the graph to stay mostly uniform and the particles to move about in it. But most rules end up with massive holes in the graph! I don't know **if any rules are known which would approximate a fluid in this manner**?

I think it should be possible as knowing the neighbours of every particle in a fluid, it should be possible to reconstruct that fluid to within reasonable errors.

One idea I had was an action function which is at a minimum when the graph is fairly uniform (with no big holes or tangles), and then define the dynamics as a path of least action.

Comment: Say for ease of visualization you started with a uniform 10x10 lattice with nearest orthogonal neighbor connections. What sort of dynamics would you expect to see?

Comment: I don't see where the topology comes in - as far as I can tell, you're just talking about a graph whose edge set (but not vertex set) changes over time.

Comment: @Ian Well I guess, imagine one of the squares of the lattice was divided into two triangles, and think of this as a particle. One could imagine rules where this "particle" might propagate around the lattice as a local anomoly. (Not my original idea but related). Or adding an extra point in one of the squares of the 10x10 lattice and seeing how this local disturbance might move around the lattice.

Comment: @Noah It's topological in the sense that distances don't matter. But yes, that is essentially describing graph theory.

Comment: @zooby But you immediately impose a metric: "We define a distance between 2 points as the shortest number of steps from neighbour to neighbour." This doesn't really have any topological content, it's just a graph theory construction.

Comment: @Noah. Yes. I guess. The question could be expressed in terms of the dynamics of locally changing graphs. In terms of are there any known rules which keep things vaguelly lattice-like while allowing local structures to propagate around the graph? (I think my original idea would not make sense because the nodes would be indistinguishable).

Comment: Googling on "graph theory fluid mechanics" leads to papers such as https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/25853/0000416.pdf%3Bsequence=1 which is probably disjoint from what you have in mind, but maybe you'll stumble across something that accords with your own ideas.